# ReflectionException Class Mint\Service\Repositories\InitRepository does not exist

Tags: laravel, exception

I get the exception

> ReflectionException Class Mint\Service\Repositories\InitRepository does not exist

How is this possible?
I already did

```
composer dump-autoload
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your vendor has a user defined codes
you should download this .rar file and extract in your laravel vendor and replace it
then your code will work find

You can download it from this link
http://www.sharways.info/mint.rar